# Why is the dative used in "и красному знамени" in the Soviet anthem?

Tags: дательный-падеж, синтаксис, согласование

I'm trying to understand why the dative is used here (last verse of the 1977 Soviet anthem):

> В победе бессмертных идей коммунизма
> Мы видим грядущее нашей страны
> И **Красному знамени** славной Отчизны
> Мы будем всегда беззаветно верны!

This line and the one above translates (roughly) to:

> We see the future of our country and **the red banner** of the glorious homeland.

I can only understand that the dative is used for indirect objects, so the accusative is more appropriate here. Can anyone explain why it's dative here?

Comment: Быть верным кому / чему - it's just the way it is.

Comment: Your translation is simply wrong.

Comment: "dative is used for indirect objects" - I don't know what you suppose here, but literally word "Дательный" (падеж) is translated as "to give, this is given" and comes from " дать, давать". "Дать кому ?" is the primary question for this case in Russian... and in Latin this is "to give" too :> : "from Latin (casus) 'dativus' ‘(cases) of giving’, from dat- ‘given’, from the verb dare ." In this case, you give your allegiance to this Red Flag.

Comment: @Пилум It would help if you familiarize yourself with the concept of [indirect object](https://glossary.sil.org/term/indirect-object) before commenting, then you would know exactly what the asker "suppose".

Comment: il--ya In the light of the foregoing it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from trying to parse it as you would an English sentence with a subject-verb-object word order. Also, in your text, there's a missing comma before the conjunction *и*, which doesn't help. If it was there, you would see more clearly that this is a compound sentence which is made up of two independent clauses joined by a coordinating conjunction *и* (and):

*В победе бессмертных идей коммунизма **мы видим грядущее** нашей страны, **и Красному знамени** славной Отчизны **мы будем** всегда беззаветно **верны**!*

In Russian, word order in sentences isn't fixed. *Красному знамени* belongs to the second clause, not the first. So in the second clause, you have the object *Красному знамени*, followed by the subject *мы*, followed by the predicate *будем верны*. If we reorder it to SVO, that's: "мы будем верны Красному знамени", and *знамени* is the indirect object here.

Comment: Are you sure it's an indirect object? Can adjectives have objects?

Comment: Yeah, it's a direct object.

Comment: @YellowSky yes I'm sure. If it's not an object, then what do you think it is?

Answer (score 6):

Your translation is wrong, the stanza literally translates to this:

> In the victory of the immortal ideas of Communism
> We see the future of our country,
> And **to the Red Banner** of the glorious fatherland
> We will be always wholeheartedly faithful.

Answer (score 5):

You are parsing it wrong.
Красному знамени here is an indirect object of верны, meaning faithful. We are faithful to the red banner. Верны красному знамени.